# Google-Visualisation chart axis bug

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, visualization

I have problem whith my google visualisation chart.
When I have small amount of data (1 - 2 records) axis are bugging by duplicating axis values:

[image: chart]

There is everything fine about the data recived by script.
Here's my chart options:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
  [
    ['Answers', 'Result', {
      role: 'style'
    }],
    @foreach(var item in question.results) {
      var str = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
      str.Append("['");
      str.Append(item.value);
      str.Append("',");
      str.Append(item.count);
      str.Append(", 'color: 6300A5', ");
      //str.Append(item.count_m);
      str.Append("],\n");


      @Html.Raw(str.ToString())
    }

  ]

);

var options = {
  chartArea: {
    width: '75%'
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'none',
    alignment: 'center'
  },
  hAxis: {
    format: '0',
    title: 'Results',
    minValuue: 0
  },
  vAxis: {
    format: '0',
    title: 'Answers'
  }
};
```

Comment: need to add decimals to `hAxis.format` or provide custom `hAxis.ticks`